# uwsgi is hanging under high pressure

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, wsgi, uwsgi, gunicorn

I am trying uwsgi:

To do so, I created a python virtual envionment and installed uwsgi in it.

I created the foobar.py sample file from the documentation :

```
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return [b"Hello World"]
```

And started uwsgi like proposed in the documentation :

```
uwsgi --http :9090 --wsgi-file foobar.py --master --processes 4 --threads 2 --logto /tmp/uwsgi.log
```

Then I used 'ab' to make a small benchmark, after 7000 requests, the bench is hung, with no reason (no message in logs) :

```
$ ab -n 10000 -c 100 http://127.0.0.1:9090/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
Completed 1000 requests
Completed 2000 requests
Completed 3000 requests
Completed 4000 requests
Completed 5000 requests
Completed 6000 requests
Completed 7000 requests
^C      <-----------------------needed to break the bench here.

Server Software:
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            9090

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        11 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   18.275 seconds
Complete requests:      7208
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      396440 bytes
HTML transferred:       79288 bytes
Requests per second:    394.41 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       253.544 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       2.535 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          21.18 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    3   0.5      3       6
Processing:     0    8   1.3      8      13
Waiting:        0    8   1.4      8      13
Total:          0   11   1.7     10      16

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     10
  66%     11
  75%     12
  80%     13
  90%     13
  95%     14
  98%     15
  99%     15
 100%     16 (longest request)
```

If I redo the test, only 3000 requests pass before a hang.
I tried with less concurrency (10 or even 1) but it still happen.
I experienced this behaviour on OS/X 10.8 and ubuntu 12.04.
I do have the same kind of behaviour with gunicorn, but it works like a charm with apache/mod_wsgi.

Could you tell me how to not get uwsgi hung on high pressure ?

Comment: Hang indefinitely, or just pauses for a second at a time? MacOS X is not a good platform to do benchmarking where you are overloading the WSGI server. The high churn of file descriptors appears to cause MacOS X to pause occasionally to do some resource cleanup, resulting in pauses. Benchmarks which overload the WSGI server like this with a hello world are also pointless as they do not tell you anything really as your real world application behaviour will be nothing like that. What are you trying to achieve anyway?

Comment: Well on MacOS, it seems to hang for at least 1 minute, on ubuntu, from time to time, it lasts "only" 30s : the speed is droping from 20000 req/s to 200 req/s because of this hang.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for digging up this old topic 7 years after your original answer, but seems like this is still a problem.

After a lot of testing I can confirm that Graham Dumpleton was right about the high churn of file descriptors causing a hang on macOS. The problem exists even when running in a Linux Docker container on macOS.

Testing the same source code on a native Linux installation doesn't produce the same error, and the application never experiences hangs.

**Solution:**

Basically, the only solution is to do any performance testing ONLY on a Linux machines, and only to use macOS for development.

Maybe someone will come-up with a clever macOS setting that fixes the problem, but based on this topic being dead for the last 7 years I don't have high hopes.

Comment: Cheers for posting an answer for 7 years old question